# how can I control the motors or joints in the gazebo

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one urdf file. where I have decleared all the links joints actuatorts etc.. I have import the model in gazebo simulator. Now I want to control the motors or joint. I have tried with pr2_controller_manager pr2_interface.. but nothing is working..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193953/how-can-i-control-the-motors-or-joints-in-the-gazebo/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to be a little more specific about what is not working....

In any case: If you have a urdf with joints in the most general case you need the robot_state_publisher to be up and running http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher and a node that publishes your joint_states, see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-10-01**:
thanks for the reply. actually my urdf is a vehical model. which have four links for four wheel. and each is connected to actuator (motor) in the urdf model. I want to run those motors. which method will be simplest. Should I do this with pr2_controller_manager or pr2_controller_interface.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-10-02**:
You might have a look at ros-control; http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control. However, I have no experience using ros_control.  Clearly, your will still need to create or find a ros driver for your low level motor controllers...